# Constant value of NSString representation

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, constants, c-preprocessor

I have a PList where I load a couple of rows of data in a dictionary. I want to add the a line like

```
<key>StandardValue</key>
<string>STANDARDVALUEFORCERTAININSTANCE</string>
```

Now when I read out the values I get a NSString. How can I get the value of the constant that I previously defined with

```
#define STANDARDVALUEFORCERTAININSTANCE 123
```

Is there a way to get the constant representation of a string? So essentially to parse it?

Comment: Maybe `<integer>123</integer>`?

Comment: It has nothing to do with being an integer... I also have a few #defined constants that are strings. It is more about getting the constant value of a string. kind of like this php function: http://php.net/constant

Comment: Probably you'd have to add a processing step to the build process, to pre-process your plist source file to do replacement.  A trivial task for a script guru, I suspect, but not something I could do off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do isn't exactly possible. The constants created with `#define` only exist at compile-time, and at run time there is no way to access them by name - they have been converted to the constant value already.

One alternative that might exist is to define a number of methods that return constant values, say in a `Constants` class. Then, at run time, load the name of the method from the plist and call it using `NSSelectorFromString()` and `performSelector:`.

However, a possible issue with this is that for safety with `performSelector:` you'd have to rewrite all your constants as Objective-C objects (since `performSelector:` returns type `id`). That could be quite inconvenient.

Nevertheless, here is an example implementation of the `Constants` class:

```
@implementation Constants : NSObject

+ (NSNumber *)someValueForACertainInstance
{
    return @123;
}

@end
```

And example usage:

```
NSDictionary *infoDotPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString *selectorName = infoDotPlist[@"StandardValue"];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName);
NSNumber *result = [Constants performSelector:selector];
```

And how the selector name would be stored in the info plist:

```
<key>StandardValue</key>
<string>someValueForACertainInstance</string>
```

Comment: NSSelectorFromString() executes a selector depending on the string read and returns a value. Why not valueForKey: then?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri That's certainly an alternative, provided the key corresponds to a method that returns a constant value. Is that what you were referring to in your answer? If so that didn't come across to me which is why I posted this suggestion.

Comment: Yes, my answer differs from the fact that uses a property (so also accessors are generated) instead of a selector.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't do it this way**. I suggest a nice alternative: KVC.

You declare this variable as class instance:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) int standardValueForCertainInstance;
```

Then you get the value with valueForKey:

```
NSString* key= dict[@"StandardValue"];
int value= [[self valueForKey: key] intValue];
```

Comment: How does KVC help with this problem?